# Code splitting on offline applications

Tags: javascript, html, web, optimization, webpack

For an **offline application** that bundles all code into a single file, is there any possible advantages of using code splitting separating `app.js` and `vendor.js` into different chunks?

> Please discard the possibility to have different modules that could load vendor chunk

Comment: In offline app, there is no possibility of loading resource fail, so, it does not matter chunking them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main goal with code splitting is to serve the user only what they need at the time. This avoids needing to download a monolithic js bundle and in theory lessens the time to interactive for a user on your app/website.

Locally they have the entire bundle anyway so I do not see any reason to split out the code.

Edit: There may be some improvemnet to the parse time to be gained by splitting the code. This depends on how the app works, if it is a react type app where the views and router handle all the functionality in the app then past the initial load there is no performance to be gained. I reccomend reading this article for js parse times https://medium.com/reloading/javascript-start-up-performance-69200f43b201

Comment: Could the bootstrap of the application be faster by having multiple files to load? I know that the browser takes time to parse and load the js file into memory, my doubt is if splitting parallelises this process and if could be faster any how.

Comment: There is some parse time associated with large js files. Depending on what your app is doing if the js is loaded in to memory already it may not be necessary to split but it may in theory provide some improved performance. I reccomend reading this article https://medium.com/reloading/javascript-start-up-performance-69200f43b201

Comment: The article is really good. As usually very focused on the typical web application case but it can be read in the details some hints that could be applied on a offline app. Using `async/defer` it's something to try, but also worth consider that browsers cache compiled code, but I've no details on how this cache is invalidated...